# Decouple Hibernate Mapping from EAR build with Wildcard Imports on Load

Tags: java, hibernate

Part 1:

I have a model.hbm.xml file that is often update, which currently requires a full project build and deployment whenever it is modified.

Can I break this out, so that the model.hbm.xml is read from the file-system, or a remote location (i.e. \file server\C$\Path\To\Hibernate\Mappings) when the application starts?

Currently I'm loading it from persistence.xml with `<mapping-file>model.hbm.xml</mapping-file>`

Part 2:

What I really want is to load all *.hbm.xml files from a specified directory when the application starts.

Is there any wildcard/directory support for loading hibernate mappings?

---

Update:

I've found a semi-solution to loading the mapping-file from a remote location

```
<mapping-file>file:////FileServerIP/path/to/hbm/model.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
```

Allows me to store the mapping file outside of the build, in a place where all servers have access.

I would like to implement this using a .properties file, so that the FileServerIP can be independent of the build as well. I haven't found out how to do that yet.

My simple attempts at loading directories/wildcards have also been unfruitful.

```
<mapping-file>file:////FileServerIP/path/to/hbm/*.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>file:////FileServerIP/path/to/hbm/</mapping-file>
```

Both failed to load the model.hbm.xml file.

Comment: Have you tried `<mapping-file>*.hbm.xml</mapping-file>` ?

Comment: I've tried with `<mapping-file>file:///C:/tmp/hbm/*.hbm.xml</mapping-file>`, which didn't work. Although `<mapping-file>file:///C:/tmp/hbm/model.hbm.xml</mapping-file>` did work.

Comment: Maybe something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947720/spring-hibernate-load-hbm-xml-from-classpath-resource

Comment: I didn't see anything there that would help, they are still trying to explicitly load each mapping-file.
I'm wondering if I can move my mapping files into a .jar, and load them during application boot from a remote location like `<jar-file>file:////FileServerIP/path/to/jar/apphbm.jar</jar-file>` but I'm not sure where to get started.